# How can I maintain relationships of the 2 tables in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a doubt in mapping relation between 2 tables in Firebase. I am currently using Firebase with iOS and I have the following situation:

I have a one user table in which I am managing basic information of user like email, name and all. Now I have other table named User-Images. Now one user has many images and I am managing Images table separately but I want to map each images with a specific user. So How can I map images for users. If you ask for DB structure that it looks similar to below.

```
{
 “Images”:[
         ID123: {
           ID: 123
           URL: "www....."
         },
         ID456: {
           ID: 456
           URL: "www....."
         }]
“User”:[
        U1: {
            Id:U1,
            Name: "MY Name"
            Images:[
              ID123,
              ID456
            }]
       }
}
```

This is my database structure and I want to establish a relation between "Images" node and the Images in the "User".

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions it's a good idea to look at your question from our eyes - we don't know the structure of your Firebase, what platform you're on or what you've tried so far. Statements like 'relationships between fields' is very vague. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question with your Firebase structure and code you've attempted (as text please, no images) and we'll take a look.